# React StoryBook - Dynamic component is not working

Tags: reactjs, button, next.js, storybook

I am using `storybook` in my react(NextJs) application.

FaqPage.stories.js,

```
import TestButton from './TestButton'

const FaqPage = {
  title: 'Button',
  component: TestButton,
}

const Template = (args) => <TestButton {...args} />

export const Index = Template.bind({})

export default FaqPage

Index.args = {
  primary: 'true',
  label: 'Hello',
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  size: 'medium',
}
```

TestButton.js,

```
const TestButton = ({ primary, backgroundColor, size, label, ...props }) => {
const mode = primary ? 'storybook-button--primary' : 'storybook-button--secondary'

 return (
   <button
     type="button"
     className={['storybook-button', `storybook-button--${size}`, mode].join(' ')}
     style={backgroundColor && { backgroundColor }}
     {...props}
   >
     {label}
   </button>
 )
}
export default TestButton
```

FaqPage is not coming in storybook(`http://localhost:6006/`). Not getting what I missed here, please help me to solve this.

Comment: Tell the error you have. Check the file name you didn't misspell with your url. Your  first page is index.js

Comment: What's the meaning of Dynamic Component?

Comment: I just tried for content page, it works. If I add button with dynamic {...args} it is not supporting. There is no error. Page is not displaying in left sidebar.